# Securing Plain Text Passwords in wso2is-5.2.0

Tags: security, wso2, password-encryption, wso2-identity-server

In my application, I am using wso2is-5.2.0 as a identity server. I want to keep my LDAP password encrypted in user-mgt.xml but i am not getting any relevant document for this. 
I tried to use below given link for password encryption, but according to this document, It is  only valid for carbon 3.2.X products.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Securing+Plain+Text+Passwords

Please let me know, any relevant document related to Securing Plain Text Passwords for wso2is-5.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the doc [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Encrypting+Passwords+with+Cipher+Tool), which is applicable for all carbon 4.4.x based products (includes IS 5.2.0)